# In what situations do verbs come before nouns?

Tags: word-order, syntax, inversion

I am not referring to questions. The song, for example, *My darling Clementine* have in some verses, cases when verbs come before:

> Dwelt a miner forty niner
>
> Drove she ducklings to the water

I've learned in affirmative sentences the subject comes first then the verb

Are there any more situations where question verbs come before subjects?

Comment: It's an inversion of word order. The standard word order for English is SVO - subject, verb, object. In some contexts, such as in poetry, in songs, in speeches, this order could be inverted to provide emphasis or for stylistic reasons. The sentence remains affirmative. See **[subject-verb inversion in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English)** at Wikipedia.

Comment: ***Think you** this is an acceptable way to ask a question?*  It's not. As @CopperKettle says, you *may* still sometimes come across usages like that, but only in archaic or poetic / highly stylised contexts. Don't plan on using it yourself in any contexts, questions or otherwise.

Comment: CopperKettle's answer is essentially correct and complete.  In songs, a songwriter will often use slightly wrong words or word order in order to make a word rhyme or have the right number of syllables.  This is not to say that your question is wrong, because it's worth asking.  But **in general, you should not take songs as good examples of standard English usage**, and if you encounter something strange in a song, your first thought should be that it is probably because of an artistic decision.

Answer (score 1):

The *Imperative Sentence* gives a command. It can end in a full stop or with an exclamation mark, depending on the forcefulness of the command.

When using the Imperative form you will most commonly see verbs come before nouns, and more often than not, verbs are the first word of the sentence. The subject of the sentence tends to be the Second Person *you*, however *you* is generally implied:

- Shut the door.
- Get off my lawn.
- Go to your room.
- Have fun storming the castle! (The Princess Bride)